# Find mongodb collection documents that have a nested object that has at least one field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4e8ae86d08101908e1000001"),
  "name" : ["Name"],
  "location" : {}
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4e8ae86d08101908e1000002"),
  "name" : ["Another ", "Name"],
  "location" : {"lat": "38.897957", "long": "-77.036560"}
}
```

#### Question

How can I query the rows that have an object with length greater than 1?

So here I would only get the record where location is known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done easily with the following command:

```
{ "location" : { $exists : true, $type : 'object', $ne : { } } }
```